# How to reset the DHCP lease?

Tags: networking, windows-xp

On Windows XP, how can I set lease time using registry or other trick, so network interface will work after that with the current DHCP lease, but after restart it will request new IP address?

If I make `ipconfig /release`, it will release IP immediately, which is not what I want. I want to do it on next boot.

I could put ipconfig /release into RunOnce, but it's also not desirable, because for some short time the old IP will be exposed. Particularly I would like to know how to manipulate lease related keys in `"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\` to achieve post-boot DHCP release.

Comment: Possibly just `ipconfig /renew`?

Comment: I do not want to change IP immediately. Renew, as far as I know will check lease time and if not expired will do nothing.

Comment: Just tested this myself. I initially ran `ipconfig /all `to check the current lease expiry time. I then ran `ipconfig /renew` and the lease time had increased from 8:25 PM to 9:17PM. This was on a Windows 10 machine, but the whole point of renewing a lease is to keep the same IP for more time, so it follows that XP would behave similarly

Comment: After boot my XP box is supposed to get totally new IP address from DHCP, which is configuring static addresses.

Comment: The DHCP protocol specifies that a device can continue to use a leased address as long as the lease remains valid, so it's not garenteed that your machine will get a new IP simply because it's rebooted, that will only happen if the previous lease expires, or is abandoned, and even then, it's entirely possible that the DHCP server could be configured to give your machine the same IP address every time based on MAC address (a DHCP reservation)

Comment: I thought lease time was set in the router, you would enter router firmware and release the lease.

Comment: @Crippledsmurf: DHCP server configuration is controlled by me. It was interesting to know how to "expire" the lease manually and whether in this state Windows would work with expired IP or request new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about running the `ipconfig /release` at shutdown?

Do Start / Run and type `gpedit.msc`

```
Computer Configuration 
/ Windows settings  
/ Scripts 
/ Shutdown 
Right-click Properties 
Click Add
```

Put `ipconfig` in the script name, and `/release` in the parameters.

Comment: There is no shutdown entry in Scripts, only logoff and logon...

Comment: @Pablo Are you in `Computer Configuration`?  The logon/logoff scripts are in `User Configuration`.  I am running a bit blind here without an XP to look at, but you could also try this in the `logoff` script if you don't have `Shutdown`

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4rHYjSS.png

Comment: So you **are** in `User Configuration` rather than `Computer Configuration`.  Would you like to try `Computer Configuration`?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work... even if I put `ipconfig /renew` as startup script. It looks like the script is running after network interface is down. DHCP server is not receiving release message. It works only from command prompt.

Comment: @Pablo Did you try it at logoff as well?

Comment: Yes, I put release in logoff as well with no result.